# Drag and Drop, source is from app or file explorer?

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a winform app which allows drag and drop. In the app is a fileListView which is a mock up of a file explorer.

I can currently drag a file from the fileListView or the file explorer.

How can I tell if the drag source is from the fileListView or from the file explorer?

I was using the e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) and seeing if the substring started with '\'. However, I've since learned that this isn't good enough because sometimes the file explorer can drag files directories starting with  '\' also.

note: all the files on the fileListView start with '\'

Comment: You can set more than one `DataFormat` when you initiate a Drag&Drop operation. You can set a specific `DataFormat` value that only your application care about. It will be ignored by the others (since other applications just don't handle it). So, when you receive a Drop request and your *custom* DataFormat value is missing, the Drop comes from some other source (this is the simple way).

Comment: DataFormats.FileDrop seems to work for both files from the explorer and files from the fileListView. Do you know another DataFormat I should try?

Comment: When you initate a DragDrop operation (`DoDragDrop`), you create a new [DataObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataobject.-ctor). The `SetData()` method can be used to set different *objects* to the `DataObject`. Some are predefined (`DataFormats.FileDrop`, for example, defines a type `string`). You can use the default formats or use a custom format, a specialized class (will be an `object` type) or simply a string format where you can store your *identifier*. When you receive a Drop request, look for this format among the others and act accordingly

Comment: The [GetDataPresent()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataobject.getdatapresent) method can be used to return a specific format from the `DataObject` you receive in a Drop request. See the examples in the Docs